# Comparing a string AND and OR at the same time

Tags: java, android, string, compare

I have a problem to compare string by using AND and OR.
I would like to display an error if the comment is empty AND "rule" equals "A" OR "B" OR "C". That's means, if "rule" equals to anything else than "A", "B" or "C" and "comment" is empty, it's fine, but in other case, it should display an error.

At this time, the && only work with equals.("C") and isEmpty. I'm not able to make it works with "A" and "B" at the same time...

The result is if equals A and comment is NOT empty, the error still appears, same for B and works fine for C...

```
    String comment = commentet.getText().toString();
    if (rule.equals("A") || rule.equals("B") || rule.equals("C") && TextUtils.isEmpty(commentaire)) {
        commentet.setError("Comment is necessary");
        return;
    }
```

Do you know how to solve this problem ?

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Should add more code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work :

```
    String comment = commentet.getText().toString();
    if ((rule.equals("A") || rule.equals("B") || rule.equals("C")) && TextUtils.isEmpty(commentaire)) {
        commentet.setError("Comment is necessary");
        return;
    }
```

Basically put your A,B,C checks inside a parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

You could use regex for the or part:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(commentaire) && rule.matches("A|B|C")){ ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
String comment = commentet.getText().toString();

if ((rule.equals("A") || rule.equals("B") || rule.equals("C")) && TextUtils.isEmpty(commentaire)) {

commentet.setError("Comment is necessary");

return;

}
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer provided from Gautam